# Media sharing между Beeline TV и Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Есть :

- ТВ Samsung
- Приставка Beeline TV
- PC под Ubuntu 18.04

Каким образом, используя приставку, которая подключенная к локальной сети, можно транслировать картинку с PC на TV?

Is it possible?

Comment: Это зависит от того какие сетевые интерфейсы присутствуют на данной приставке и на какой платформе приставка (Android или...). Я думаю это больше вопрос не для данного ресурса, а в службу поддержки Beeline

Comment: @VladSpirin могу посмотреть сетевые интерфейсы, но сейчас используется костыль вида "Screen cast в общую папку -> Beeline TV берёт его с общей папки -> Происходит трансляция"
Думаю можно подумать как к ViewPort подключиться или начать хостить "канал" в локальной сети и используя поиск каналов на приставке найти канал